Solenoid driver circuit with peak hold
Many fine solutions for making a “peak hold” Solenoid driver, like TI DRV104/DRV120/TPS1H000 (1-channel), Maxim/Analog devices MAX22200 (8-channel).
But they are sole source, so the price will surely increase over time.
All the above solutions are using MOSFET, but could a solution with a BJT be possible?
The solenoid used in the application is using 12 V DC @30 mA peak and 10mA for hold. Resistance is around 300 ohm. So a low Rdson is not essential.
So would a BJT solution be possible? Will it be possible to control the current by PWM, a feedback current sense to ensure the power needed.
Another advantage of the BJT could be to choose a base current so the BJT also could be used as a current limiter, in case you need 16 outputs using the same power source and would avoid one shortcut could turn other active outputs off.
Have anyone experience with using a BJT with PWM. Would 10 kHz be possible?

Voltage measured over 30 ohm resistor in series with the solenoid.
The duration of the peak(hit) pulse should 30 ms (Ihit = 30mA) if you compare the to pictures.
Somewhere in a datasheet is written that the best solution from a power perspective is to use the current and not the voltage to control the hold power. Could this be because the resistance of the coil will change over temperature and thereby the current (in voltage mode) and thereby you need to add extra voltage to ensure that the plunger will stay pulled in?

Added additional specification:
Digital High-Side Output Design Specification Summary
Temperature Range:
• Operating Temperature (Ta): -10°C to 60°C
Output Configuration:
• 2 groups of 4 outputs on the same PCB
Power Supply per Group:
• Output Voltage: 8V to 12.4V
• Maximum Output Current: 60mA
Power Efficiency:
• Must be a power-saving solution.
• Outputs should have the option to be always on or always off.
Thermal Management:
• Maximum Junction-to-Ambient Thermal Resistance (RθJA): 26.88°C/W
• Maximum Power Dissipation: 744mW (calculated at 12.4V * 60mA)
Control Specifications:
• Control via CPU output with the following characteristics:
◦ Vcc: 3.0V to 3.6V
◦ PWM Frequency: 0–30kHz
◦ Duty Cycle: 0–100%
Output Requirements:
• The output must be capable of controlling a coil (inductive load) with an integrated flyback diode.
Will the best solution to use a charge pump circuit that can be shared between the N channel mosfets to control the output fets? Will a push pull driver circuit be necessary for shfting the mosfet upto 30kHz?

BJTs and MOSFETs both switch well at lower frequencies, the question rather is: can you find a controller that does it?  Or, are you interested in crafting a discrete solution from building blocks (oscillator, gates, etc.) and the parts cost isn't such a concern -- or the expected availability/risk of single-source parts is stronger?

Using current instead of voltage may be some better, but not sure it's worth the added complexity to control that instead of voltage.  Just use a hold voltage sufficiently above the minimum to insure that it stays held at temperature.

The target was to decrease the power used for the solenoid and finding the DRV104 a 1 chip solution gave my first yes, this is just what I need. I prefer a high side solution so the energy is not available on the solenoid in case you by accident connect a screwdriver to gnd and the solenoid activates. But the price was $2-3 and I needed 8 on the board. The next solution was MAX22200, it can do all I need so it was perfect but again the price, Maxim/Analog devices:-(. Then high side discrete solution there is a lot to consider on mosfets when you need a upto 100 kHz PWM. Then this post.....

@Erik - Hi, Where did this image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/etc. name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

@SamGibson, the picture came from the Max22200 datasheet
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX22200.pdf

Below is the LTspice sim of a PWM Hit & Hold circuit for the solenoid:
It uses a CD4093 quad Schmitt-trigger NAND gate to generate a 10kHz PWM signal, which holds the solenoid at 10mA after the initial application of the full 12V to pull in the solenoid.
The duty-cycle that determines the hold current is set by pot U5.
The PWM frequency is determined by the resistance value of the pot and C1.
The full voltage is initially applied for a time (here about 130ms) as determined by R3-C2 time-constant.
The solenoid driver is a small N-MOSFET which is easy to drive and has a low Vds on.



advantage of the BJT could be to choose a base current so the BJT also could be used as a current limiter

It doesn't matter much if it would be a BJT or a MOSFET, since the control of the current has to be done closed-loop. That's because the BJT current gain/transconductance varies a lot between within the same model of the transistor/mosfet. So the fact that a base consumes any current at all is an inconvenience more than a benefit, you can't really depend on the gain to be constant.

If there are many solenoids to drive, then the simplest overall approach is a 12V supply, then a 3.3-4.0V buck fed from it for the hold voltage. That will provide about 10mA to the solenoids, depending on whether there is a series diode or not. That way there is only one buck, and the solenoid drivers are rather simple.
Solutions with an external switch
All of the solutions below need an external low-side driver for the solenoid. That driver can be a small relay, a low-side BJT or mosfet driver, etc. It just needs to hard-switch, our circuit will take care of switching from the 12V supply to the hold supply.
The duration of the initial pulse is proportional to the capacitance of C1. For a shorter pulse, make C1 smaller.
Passive Solution
Switching from 12V down to 4V for each solenoid is rather easy, no BJTs needed. The time constant for the R1-C1 combo is a rather long 1.5s, so this will work if the solenoid has about 15s or longer dwell time when it's off.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Single-BJT Solution
With a BJT we can use a much smaller capacitor, and the dwell time is reduced to 2s:

simulate this circuit

Those circuits may be simple but they are not particularly satisfying.
A current-mirror + mosfet solution
It would be nice to have a hard-switching solution that doesn't need long dwell times. A mosfet will help with that:

simulate this circuit
Q1-Q2 is a current mirror that charges C1 when the mosfet is driving current into the solenoid. It drives a small current (<1mA) even during the hold time, so the dissipation on D1 and M1 are essentially the same. This small fraction of the hold current through M1 is copied by Q2-Q1 onto C1||R1, keeping the mosfet "almost off" during hold time.
The solenoid current waveform looks respectable:

The dwell time needed to discharge C1 is about 0.5s.

Later we can investigate solutions that have built-in switching function, so that an external switch won't be needed.
